# Random issues with ViewEngine in Nancy 2.0.0 pre-release

Tags: nancy

I've been experiencing some odd issues with my application that I am not sure how to go about tracking down because it is so random. I was wondering if there may be any ideas based on the stack trace below.

Here is some quick bullet points:

- Issue seems to be related to code in the View (.cshtml)
- It RANDOMLY appears and it has something to do with the session cookie because if you try from another computer then it is no issue or if you clear your cache it is no issue
- My GetUserByIdentifier is wrapped in a try{}catch{} which returns NULL if we enter the catch{}.. which should redirect to the login screen.

Could this be something internal causing the error message? This unhandled exception can even happen on my login.cshtml page which doesn't even have any code in the view.

The error message:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource) +72
   System.SZArrayHelper.get_Item(Int32 index) +13816967
   Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorViewEngine.GetLineNumber(Int32 startLineIndex, IReadOnlyList`1 compilationSource) +39
   Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<BuildErrorMessages>b__0(Diagnostic error) +118
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +80
   System.Linq.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() +51
   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +250
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +106
   Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorViewEngine.BuildErrorMessages(IEnumerable`1 errors, IList`1 templateLines, IReadOnlyList`1 compilationSource) +272
   Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorViewEngine.BuildErrorMessage(EmitResult result, ViewLocationResult viewLocationResult, String sourceCode) +366
   Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<GenerateRazorViewFactory>b__0() +49
   Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorViewEngine.GetViewInstance(ViewLocationResult viewLocationResult, IRenderContext renderContext, Object model) +1064
   Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<RenderView>b__0(Stream stream) +4700
   Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.<ProcessRequest>d__2.MoveNext() +381
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +13891908
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar) +69
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +178
```

Comment: Issue was opened for this: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/2731